# border-top in a A element

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I need some help setting a border-top for a A element. As you can see [here](http://comvivem.treswd.com/net/) the button, which is a A styled element, have a

```
<hr>
```

positioned absolute and then move from top to bottom to achieve the behavior but this work for this button (notice the width:85% in the HR) but if I want the same behavior in the rest of the buttons of all the site then this approach wont work cause the width:85%. So my question is: it's possible to get the same behavior setting a border-top for the A element? The border top must have the same width as main button but leaving a padding: 0 5px as you may notice.

Thanks and cheers in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, make the `<a>` act like a block element:

```
a{
   display:block;
   border-top: 2px solid #FCC;
 }
```

This will give a top border, the same color as your hr, to all `<a>` elements in your html.

or you could just apply it to your button class which you have on `<a>` tags already:

```
.button{
   display:block;
   border-top: 2px solid #FCC;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @ryan using your suggestion and with some others changes it works now, the code looks like `.button{background:url('../images/comvivem/button_primary.png') repeat-x 0 0;height:23px;width:auto;border:1px solid #FBDCA5;padding:0;text-align:center}
.button a{font-family:'Tahoma',sans-serif;font-size:11px;color:#000;cursor:pointer;font-weight:400;line-height:16px;display:block;border-top:1px solid #FFCCCC;margin:2px 3px 0;}`

Comment: could you please help me to apply the same behavior to a BUTTON or input type="SUBMIT" element? I can apply all but not the border-top positioned as is in the A element :(

Comment: Can you link to what you are trying to do with the button element or input element? I can help a lot more if I see what your trying to do.

Comment: Ok, first thx for your fast reply @ryan, now to explain a bit. Go to http://comvivem.treswd.com/net and use demo/demo123 to access. After that notice how looks the **COMENTAR** button (which isn't a button is a < a > element). I want the same behavior for example in button **BUSCAR** at left widget called "Buscar Contenidos" this is what I want

Comment: your style for the `<a>` tag is actually on the div surrounding it. Well a button is naturally a block element just like a div. So have you tried applying the same css-classes to the button that you have on the div around the `<a>` tag ?

Comment: you're right it works but I lost the border-top (the tinny line that A have as border-top) and I need it to maintain the same aspect across the site